# Pandas groupby without any aggregating operations

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below, and I am trying to "group" by Col1 (see desired output). This should be obvious, but I must not be searching for the right key words. Everything I try with groupby either returns a series or seems to need some kind of aggregation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A','B','A','B','B','B','A','A','B',],
                   'Col2': ['q','e','r','y','c','a','j','g','v',],
                   'Col3': [1,13,5,22,13,2,5,9,12],
                   })
```

```
  Col1 Col2  Col3
0    A    q     1
1    B    e    13
2    A    r     5
3    B    y    22
4    B    c    13
5    B    a     2
6    A    j     5
7    A    g     9
8    B    v    12
```

Desired output:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
   A    q       1
        r       5
        j       5
        g       9
   B    e       13
        y       22
        c       13
        a       2
        v       12
```

Comment: what is supposed to be the purpose of this? Is this for printing only or will this be followed by a transformation?

Comment: @Racooneer printing/display and plotting stacked bar chart

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, this should achieve your goal: Multiindexing

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A','B','A','B','B','B','A','A','B',],
                   'Col2': ['q','e','r','y','c','a','j','g','v',],
                   'Col3': [1,13,5,22,13,2,5,9,12],
                   })
print(df.set_index(["Col1", "Col2"]).sort_index())
```

This would be the output: the only issues for you, I'm not sure about, is the height of the index cols vs the value cols.

```
            Col3
Col1 Col2      
A    g        9
     j        5
     q        1
     r        5
B    a        2
     c       13
     e       13
     v       12
     y       22
```